# On Tomcat Server Using Yii Framework HTTP_X_USERNAME locally recognized but not online

Tags: api, rest, http, yii

I prepared an api using yii framework. The api contains an authentication method which checks the HTTP_X_USERNAME and HTTP_X_PASSWORD parameters and compares them with some data in the database.

While testing everything locally on the test dev (WAMP + Eclipse + Tomcat) it worked normally. I tested everything with the Postman. I have put those two parameters (HTTP_X_...) into the header.

After I uploaded the api to the production server (Tomcat) the api always returns authentication FALSE although the authorization data locally and online is the same. The code stops at the part where it checks if those parameters are even set "You must be authorized to access the api. No USERNAME and PASSWORD set.".

Does any one have an idea where the problem is? Why does it work locally and not online???

```
private function _checkAuth() {

        $headers = apache_request_headers ();

        if (! (isset ( $headers ['HTTP_X_USERNAME'] ) and isset ( $headers ['HTTP_X_PASSWORD'] ))) {
            // Error: Unauthorized
            $this->badResponse ( 401, 'You must be authorized to access the api. No USERNAME and PASSWORD set.');
        }

        $username = $headers ['HTTP_X_USERNAME'];
        $password = $headers ['HTTP_X_PASSWORD'];

        // Find the user
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria ();
        $criteria->addCondition ( 'email = :email'); 
        $criteria->addCondition( 'api_access_token = :pass');
        $criteria->params = array(':email' => $username, ":pass" => $password);

        $school = AutoSchool::model ()->find ( $criteria );

        if ($school === null) {
            $this->badResponse ( 401, 'Error: You must be authorized to access the api.' );
        }

        return $school->id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem!

After debuging found that the problem was the method apache_request_headers() since it did not return anything useful which i set in the header.

I implemented my own method

```
private function apache_request_headers2() {
            foreach($_SERVER as $key=>$value) {
                if (substr($key,0,5)=="HTTP_") {
                    $key=str_replace(" ","-",ucwords(strtolower(str_replace("_"," ",substr($key,5)))));
                    $out[$key]=$value;
                }else{
                    $out[$key]=$value;
                }
            }
            return $out;
        }
```

But this is not all. I had to change the header parameters i was requesting. I had to use $headers ['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and $headers ['PHP_AUTH_PW'] instead of HTTP_X_USERNAME and HTTP_X_PASSWORD.

And finally while issuing the POST request I had to use Basic Authentication and not setting the Header parameters

[image: Setting the AUthentication parameters in Postman]

[image: Headers]

And the complete code of the edited method:

```
private function _checkAuth() {

        $headers = $this->apache_request_headers2();

        if (! (isset ( $headers ['PHP_AUTH_USER'] ) and isset ( $headers ['PHP_AUTH_PW'] ))) {
            // Error: Unauthorized
            $this->badResponse ( 401, 'You must be authorized to access the api. No USERNAME and PASSWORD set.');
        }

        $username = $headers ['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
        $password = $headers ['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

        // Find the user
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria ();
        $criteria->addCondition ( 'email = :email'); 
        $criteria->addCondition( 'api_access_token = :pass');
        $criteria->params = array(':email' => $username, ":pass" => $password);

        $school = AutoSchool::model ()->find ( $criteria );

        if ($school === null) {
            $this->badResponse ( 401, 'Error: You must be authorized to access the api.' );
        }

        return $school->id;
    }
```